# Visual studio keymaps in netbeans (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, netbeans

Is there's a keymap profile for Netbeans that replicate Visual studio's keymapping?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not possible to map keys depending our your actions (like in VS) its not possible to get an *exact* dublicate of VS keymapping. Anyway you can make your own:

**`Tools -> Options -> Keymap -> Manage Profiles`** there you duplicate the current one *(as a backup)*

Now you can change the key's towards VS2010.

Comment: unfortunately not and i cant say if here's one available yet. in worst-case you have to map the keys you need by your own.